# Check each values on Column a column with another column values

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, dax

Is there any way in **Excel** or in **DAX** i can check if all the values of a single column exist or don't on another column.

Example - I have a column called **Column 1** where i have some values, like 4,5,2,1. now i want to check how many of those values exists on **Column 2** !

As an Output, i expected it can Go `Green` if the value exists else `Red`.

[image]

I have looked in a lot of place but the only useful result i have found where i can find for a sngle value, not for all the values in a single column.

Do anyone knows any way of doing this work !

Comment: Any reason why this is tagged `[python]` ?

Comment: @jpp i was thinking a is there any possibility it can be implemented using any python script

Comment: Conditional formatting as formula `=COUNTIF(B:B,$A2)>0` for Green and `=COUNTIF(B:B,$A2)=0` for Red

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor thank you for your answer, it works.

Comment: @ChristoferHansen, in your question it seems you want the whole column go red if one value is missing. Go green when all are present in column B. Is that correct? Or are the answers provided sufficient?

Comment: @ChristoferHansen, check my answer below, hope it will help you to make it easy as you wished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention Python, this is possible programmatically with the Pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd

# define dataframe, or read in via df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [4, 5, 2, 1] + [np.nan]*4,
                   'col2': [6, 8, 3, 4, 1, 6, 3, 4]})

# define highlighting logic    
def highlight_cols(x):
    res = []
    for i in x:
        if np.isnan(i):
            res.append('')
        elif i in set(df['col2']):
            res.append('background: green')
        else:
            res.append('background: red')
    return res

# apply highlighting logic to first column only
res = df.style.apply(highlight_cols, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['col1']])
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are simply the best of the best, thank you for your answer. Anyone who is facing this issue i would suggest them to try this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create a *(optionally hidden)* column that will be adjacent to your search column *(in my example that will be column C to column B)*

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$A$4, 1, 0)), FALSE, TRUE)`

This will determine, if the value is contained within the first data-list (returns true if it is)
And then just use simple conditional formatting

[image]

Provides the result as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily without adding hidden columns as below. This will updated anytime if you change numbers in column A.

1. Select column B
2. Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format
3. insert formula as `=OR(B2=$A$2,B2=$A$3,B2=$A$4,B2=$A$5) = TRUE` and format cell as your wish (here in Green)
4. Repeat steps 1 to 2
5. insert formula as `=OR(B2=$A$2,B2=$A$3,B2=$A$4,B2=$A$5) = FASLE` and format cells as your wish (here in Red)
6. Select the column name cell (To remove column heading formatting)
7. Conditional Formatting -> Clear Rule -> Clear Rules from selected cells

[image: Result]

Comment: Nice. Please accept if this is the correct answer you wanted.